# Copy dir and its contents in RAM and backup on the original dir

Tags: rsync, tmpfs, bind-mount

I'd like to copy a dir and its contents in RAM, do my routines and periodically make some backups/sync on my original dir.

So if I have a dir `mydir/` with 2 files:

```
$ ls mydir/
file1.tex  file2.tex
```

I can mount it with:

```
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=100m tmpfs ~/mydir
```

but the mounted one it's empty (as expected):

```
$ ls mydir/
$
```

1 - Is it possible to keep the original `mydir`'s contents in my mounted `mydir`?

2 - Is it possible to sync (let's say, every 5 minutes) the mounted `mydir` with `mydir` on the hard drive? I red about the bind option but I'm not sure of how it works.

Comment: It shows as empty because you are mounting a temporary filesystem over your existing `mydir` directory.

Comment: @Peschke Now that I understood. I wondered if is it possible to keep making operation on that dir (the HD one).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can keep your current mydir contents. Explore `mount --bind`

Yes, it is possable to sync every 5 minutes with like `rsync` and the `mount --bind` commands.

I would however, make a separate directory to mount:

Say, `mkdir /home/user/memdrive`.

You should make a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if mount | grep /home/user/memdrive > /dev/null; then
    cp /home/user/memdrive /mydir
    else
    mount -t tmpfs -o size=100M tmpfs /home/user/memdrive
    cp /mydir /home/user/memdrive
    umount /home/user/memdrive
fi
```

If the memdrive is not mounted it will mount it and copy the contense of /mydir to it.

If the memdrive is mounted it will `cp` /home/user/memdrive back to /mydir then unmount.

Modify to suit your needs.

You could also do all of these manually or do them in a different script.